# update one MySQL table value based on another by id match based on aggregation of points

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get aggregation of value from one table **(user_tranz)** and looking to store in to update / insert into another table (users) based on ( id of **users** found in **user_tranz**
have these 2 mysql tables structure :

1- users:

```
    id      coin  buy  added  free   pay_later  renewed   pro
=========== ==== ===== ====== ==== =========== ========== ===
          1 0     0      0     0       0           0       0
          2 0     0      0     0       0           0       0
          3 0     0      0     0       0           0       0
```

2- user_tranz:

```
  id (AI)     user_id coin  buy  added  free   pay_later  renewed   pro
========== =========== ==== ===== ====== ==== =========== ========== ===
       99           1    10   5      10     10       20           50     100
       98           2    5    5      10     10       20           50     10
       97           3    5    5      10     10       20           50     25
       96           3    0    0      10     10       20           50     10
       95           3    10   5      0      0        20           50     5
       94           2    10   5      10     10       20           50     10
```

So far i know this can be done by something like this **(LEFT JOIN with COALESCE())** but i don't know how to get aggregation of value than store multiple at once using join

> Expected results:

```
Users:
    id      coin  buy  added  free   pay_later  renewed   pro
=========== ==== ===== ====== ==== =========== ========== ===
    1        10    5     10    10      20         50      100
    2        15    10    20    20      40        100      20
    3        15    10    20    20      60        150      40
```

Comment: Can you describe what kind of *result* do you expect?

Comment: @TamasRev - added Expected results in question

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
UPDATE users u 
SET u.coin = (
    SELECT SUM(ut.coin) 
    FROM user_tranz ut 
    WHERE ut.user_id = u.id
), ...
```

You can use a subquery to determine the value to insert in the update query.